# How to consume a soap application using another soap application

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

Java 8 and spring boot v2.2.1

I am having 2 applications App1 and App2. App2 is generating wsdl file and has some business logic. I want to consume App2 in App1 which I want to develop in soap web services. When I hit the request it should go from App1 to App2 and return the response. Is it possible to consume one soap service in other? If yes, How can I make soap call with input request dynamically.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

### Contract

First of all, start with your contract between service and clients. It is either WSDL or Java POJOs generating WSDL afterwards.

### Web Service

Then, you should be developing your back-end (App2 in your example).

[This Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) is explaining just that.

### Client

App1 should be your SOAP client.

[This Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) should help you get started with that.

### Dev Tools

During development, a SOAP testing tool like [SOAPUi](https://www.soapui.org/) should help you.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Thanks for the response. I have developed the both applications. But I am not able to get how to send the request input to App1 Client App. I want to send the request from soapUi that triggers the App1(App2 will be connecting in backend) and sends the response from App1.

Comment: App1 needs to build the request in Java. You need to instantiate Java objects using classes generated from your WSDL, then use the WebServiceTemplate class to send the Java objects to the App2 endpoint (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#marshalSendAndReceive(java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback))